# Get messages 'from' or 'of' a user?

Tags: prepositions

What is the right way to say you want to retrieve all messages from a user (for example when you describe a database query that gets all user messages)?

"Get the reports **from** the user"

"Get the reports **of** the user"

Comment: I don't think either is incorrect, but the second sounds odd because of the other meanings of "of." (Now there's a sentence for ya!") Specifically, it sounds a bit like you could be asking for reports *about* the user. I would certainly use the word "all" in your sentence: "Get all (the) reports ..." You could sidestep the issue completely by using a possessive: "Get all the user's messages."

Answer (score 1):

"Gather all user messages" or "Gather user reports" leaves less room for misinterpretation. "Get the reports from the user" could imply that you are getting reports from the user directly, as in, they are sending the messages. The other implies the reports are about the user.